# Adding Key, Values to Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

```
Dictionary<int,int> dic = new Dictionary<int,int>();
```

What is the difference between below to approach to add key, value to dictionary?

```
dic[key]=value;
dic[key]=value1;  //its allowing me to update the value for the same key. No error.
```

vs

```
dic.Add(key,value);
dic.Add(key,value1); //it doesn't allow to update the value to the key as key already exists.
```

Comment: You answered your own question. The first is an update, the second is attempting to add a new key. Dictionaries can't have duplicate keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the intended behavior of this property and the `.Add` method.

From the documentation on the [Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.Item[TKey] Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.item?view=net-6.0):

> Gets or sets the value associated with the specified key.
> ...
> If the specified key is not found, [...] a set operation creates a new element with the specified key.

Compare that with the documentation on the [Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.Add(TKey, TValue) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.add?view=net-6.0) method, which says that an `ArgumentException` will be thrown when "[a]n element with the same key already exists in the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`."